# Typescript Infer return value for multiple Error subclasses

Tags: typescript

I have a function that can return a number, an `Error`, or a `NegativeError`:

```
class NegativeError extends Error {
  name = 'NegativeError'
}

function doThing (a: number): number | NegativeError | Error {
  return a < 0 ? new NegativeError() : a === 0 ? new Error() : a
}
const done = doThing() // T | NegativeError | Error
```

However, when I remove the signature's explicit return type, typescript drops the `Error` & only infers `T | NegativeError` as return type:

```
function doThing (a: number) {
  return a < 0 ? new NegativeError() : a === 0 ? new Error() : a
}
const done = doThing() // T | NegativeError
```

As a hack, I can force it to keep the return types discrete by using a constructor function, which maintains the prototypical inheritance:

```
function NegativeError(message: string) {
  Error.call(this)
  this.message = message
  this.name = 'NegativeError'
}
NegativeError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype)
NegativeError.prototype.constructor = NegativeError
```

I'd like to avoid this because it isn't easy to read & contains the typescript error: `An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container`.

Is there any way to make typescript correctly infer all return types?

Comment: You declared `doThing` with a parameter but you're calling it without any argument - I guess this is just a typo, but please check.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like you're falling afoul of Typescript's [structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system). Your `NegativeError` class is structurally equivalent to the `Error` class, so as far as Typescript is concerned, these two types are subtypes of each other:

```
// type Test = true
type Test = Error extends NegativeError ? true : false
```

So since `Error` is a subtype of `NegativeError`, the union `NegativeError | Error` can be simplified to just `NegativeError`, or alternatively, since `NegativeError` is also a subtype of `Error`, the union `Error | NegativeError` can be simplified to just `Error`; either way.

This wouldn't happen in a language with a [nominal type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) (e.g. Java), but in Typescript the fact that `NegativeError` is declared as a *subclass* and has a different name, does not mean it is a different type. If you want to distinguish it then you can change its structure, e.g. by refining the type of the `name` property:

```
class NegativeError extends Error {
  name: 'NegativeError' = 'NegativeError'
}
```

Now `Error` is no longer a subtype of `NegativeError`, but `NegativeError` is still a subtype of `Error`, so the union `NegativeError | Error | number` will be simplified to `Error | number`. Which should be fine, because `NegativeError` is still assignable to that union type.

Comment: any way to ensure the return type is `NegativeError | Error | number`? Makes sense that NegativeError is collapsed into Error, but that's what I'd like to avoid

Comment: You would have to make it so that `NegativeError` is not a subtype of `Error` or vice versa. Or use a union of different types, like `{kind: 'Error', error: Error} | {kind: 'NegativeError', error: NegativeError} | {kind: 'number', value: number}`, where the different branches of the union are disjoint because of the `kind` property.

Comment: this helped! I found I could avoid the discriminated union if i created a class & then set the prototype to the Error prototype. In doing so, javascript thinks it's an error, but typescript doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct solution to the core inference issue but yet another workaround is to wrap your "normal" error into another subtype :

```
class NegativeError extends Error {
  name = 'NegativeError'
}
class BError extends Error {
  name = 'BError'
}

function doThing(a: number) {
  return a < 0 ? new NegativeError() : a === 0 ? new BError() : a
}
const done = doThing(1) // infers doThing(a: number): number | NegativeError | BError
```

Answer (score 0):

Since typescript looks for `extend` to determine the super, I determined I couldn't use that.

I tried to extend an `Error` without using the extend keyword. I achieved that by setting the NegativeError prototype equal to the Error prototype:

```
class NegativeError {
  message: string
  name: 'NegativeError' = 'NegativeError'

  constructor(message: string) {
    this.message = message
  }
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(NegativeError.prototype, Error.prototype)
```

Thanks to @kaya3 for pointing me in the right direction!